# Getting the integer value of ENUM in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, enums

I have a DropdownList in my View with stored Enum Values.

```
public enum UserRole
{
    ADMINISTRATOR = 1,
    APPROVER = 2,
    ORDER = 3
}

 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.New_User.Role , new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(soukohin.Models.Admin.UserRole))), "Select Role", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "new_role", @placeholder = "役割" , @onchange = "getRoleInformation(this)" })
```

after selecting the value, I want to get the Integer value of this from Javascript.

I tried this code, but the return value is the Name of Enum.

```
 function getRoleInformation(value) {
       alert(value.value);
    }
```

SAMPLE RESULT: `ORDER`

How can I get the integer value, not the name of the enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving the ArrayList constructor basically an array of strings.

The following might work:

replace

```
new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(soukohin.Models.Admin.UserRole)))
```

with

```
new SelectList((new System.Collections.ArrayList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(soukohin.Models.Admin.UserRole)))).Cast<soukohin.Models.Admin.UserRole>().Select(e => new KeyValuePair<int,string>((int)e,e.ToString())).ToArray(),"Key","Value")
```